# Magento 2: Get Order Info From Invoice

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, magento2.3

Using Magento 2.3, I'm trying to get a custom attribute from the order and save it to the invoice when the invoice is first created.

I already have the custom attributes setup and saving to the order when order is first placed, but can't seem to pass that variable and save it to the invoice once that's created.

I have an observer for the event `sales_order_invoice_pay`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd"> 
    <event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
        <observer name="salesrep_sales_order_invoice_pay" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\Invoice\Salesrep"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and my observer:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\Invoice;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Salesrep implements ObserverInterface
{

  protected $messageManager;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
  ){
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    try {
      $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
      $order = $invoice->getOrder();
      $salesrep = $order->getData('salesrep');
      $invoice->setSalesrep($salesrep);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The custom order attribute that I'm trying to save to invoice is called `salesrep`, I've confirmed that the salesrep is saving properly to the Order but not saving to the invoice.

---

EDIT: Here is the code I'm using to save salesrep to the order initially.

`events.xml`

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="salesrep_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\Order\Salesrep"/>
    </event>
```

My observer:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Salesrep implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
  ){
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
  }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    try {
        $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->get($order->getCustomerEmail(), $websiteId = 1);
        $salesrep = $customer->getCustomAttribute('salesrep')->getValue();
        $order->setSalesrep($salesrep);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $noSuchEntityException) {
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of retrieving order from sale repository you can retrieve order from $invoice object like this `$order = $invoice->getOrder();`

Comment: Thanks Aman, good call.  I've updated my code which got rid of the ID NULL error, however now the order attribute isn't saving to the invoice.  I've updated my question.  Any idea?

Comment: You log `$order->getSalesrep()` and check its fetching from order or not.

Comment: looks like `$order->getSalesrep()` is returning NULL, I'm using Braintree as payment processor, I'm wondering if it's creating the invoice before the order is completely done saving.

Comment: Ok then log order data object as well as try to save a static string as salesrep for invoice lets see where is the error.

Comment: `$invoice->setSalesrep('test');` setting a static value worked, but yeah for some reason salesrep is returning NULL on order data object, even though I can see the value in the DB.  I'm initially adding the salesrep to order via `sales_order_place_after` , I'm wondering if that's not registering before the invoice is created.

Comment: Please share the code where you are saving `salesrep` during the order created.Also Is there any files name `extension_attribute.xml` to this module

Comment: @AmitBera Updated with my code on how I'm saving `salesrep` initially when an order is placed.  It's being pulled from the customer's account.  I do not have any files named `extension_attribute.xml` in my module.

Comment: @AJ47 you are setting representative object after place order, seems `salesrep_sales_order_place_after` is running after `salesrep_sales_order_invoice_pay`,  try setting it before place order in order object so that it will get retrieved by `salesrep_sales_order_invoice_pay`

Comment: @AmanAlam `sales_order_place_after` seemed to do the trick -- funny I thought I had tested that already but apparently I overlooked that.  In any case, thank you guys for the help!  Not sure if you want to write that up as an official answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: @AJ47 its great to know that your work is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use events

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```

To save data to order instead of **sales_order_place_after**

And

```
sales_order_invoice_register
```

To save data to invoice instead of **sales_order_invoice_pay**

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks! Although I didn't test these, you were def pointing in the right direction.  I ended up using `sales_order_place_before` to make sure salesrep was saved before the invoice was created.